# How to receive IR signal in PIC18F

Tags: infrared, pic18

I need to receive signal from IR transmitter LED. I am not sure how to program the microcontroler. I am looking for some concept, how to do that. Whether I have to use A/D conversion? How to synchronize transmitter and receiver? What structure will be in coming data? Let's say that I assumed 600us for 0 (binary 0) and 1200 for 1 (binary 1) when I was programming a transmitter. What are the common steps to receive infrared transmission on PIC18F microcontroler?

Comment: Try http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the protocol you're trying to send over IR. If you can use RS232 and FM, then you just need an FM decoder (a PLL will do) and you can connect it to the PIC's serial port.